# Webb app performance android

Tags: android, cordova, dojo, sencha-touch, jqtouch

I'm developing a webbapp for iOS and Android, primarily. The problem is that it tends to run slow on the android phone (testing made on Samsung Galaxy S2). I've tried a couple of different frameworks together with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) without any good result.

My experience this far (on android):

**[Dojo toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/mobile):** (v1.7.1)
Pretty good but flickers alot when doing transitions between different views and the input forms performs badly.

**[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/):** (v1.1)
Not very responsive and flickers a bit during transitions. Changing orientation takes awfully long.

**[JQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/)**: (beta 4)
Runs smooth but the layout is broken on android (back-buttons etc that uses CSS transform rotate and translate)

**My question is**: 
Have any of you found a framework that works well on both iPhone and Android devices? or is the only solution to develop native?

On a side note I've noticed that [Sencha touch 2.0](http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-2-developer-preview/) has focused on Android performance but there's only a developer preview available at this time and is not going to be release before Q2 2012.

Comment: You might look at ember.js, but my sense is that the Android browser is somewhat finicky and unreliable. Have you noticed that the Android browser has a much lower web traffic market share than Mobile Safari, despite the fact that more people own Android phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have found is that many of the frameworks work just great but the root cause of the problems is earlier versions of Android's support for CSS3 style transitions. You are probably better off avoiding or disabling these transitions.

Comment: I've changed from API level 7 to 10 and it still performs bad. Sure, I'd be able to go even further but that would mean that the app would be useless since there are too few users.

Comment: Yes, I think you should keep your minimum API level at 7 as you will be able to target the largest slice of Android users. Even moving up to a 3.X version of Android doesn't help CSS3 transitions that much. This is definitely an area in which Android is lacking. Try to limit the transitions in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I will go with native version for android in this release and make a new try on webbapps for android later on.